# Timestamp and form input date/time

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli, datepicker

I have not got any code built yet as I need to ask this question before I can start making it.

first what I am doing:
I am going to be making a tournament system on my website and I would like the tournament creators to choose a date and time that tournament will be active for signups and closed for signups.

I believe I will be using www.jongsma.org datepicker as I think it is very nice looking and easy to use for the end user. [Link:here](http://jongsma.org/software/protoplasm/control/datepicker?page=datepicker)

**The Question:**

After sanitizing the input from the forms date/time do I need to specify for it to be converted from the users (Person inserting the time) local time to UTC before I store the data on the database or does it automatically convert the input from there local time to UTC when the data is being written to the database?

I am using **MySQLite**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL accepts datetime in this format "Y-m-d H:i:s".
You can always convert different formatted dates into unix_timestamp with [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) and turn it into mysql date format with:

```
$unix_time = strtotime($differentFormattedDate);
date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$unix_time);
```

Comment: He need to pass date/time. So the format should be "Y-m-d H:i:s"

Comment: ok that is awesome. Thank you for the response. Do you know how I convert it back to the viewers local time so if I was to display the `$unix_time` on my site the viewer sees their local time instead of the `$unix_time`. I am guessing the `$differentFormattedDate` is the variable I make from the initial _POST data what I get from the the form itself e.g. `$differentFormattedDate = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9_-]#i', '', $_POST['time_date']);`

Comment: yes $differentFormattedDate is the one you get from datepicker. by local time do you mean local format? or local time? if you'd like to set format there is a function just for that: strftime (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) 

`echo strftime ( 'd/m/Y H:i:s', $unix_time );`
don't forget to use setlocale first to set your users locale.

Comment: OK that is awesome man. Thank you a bunch. I was referring to the local time and not format as 8pm in the UK isn't 8pm in the USA. Thank you once again.

Comment: well you should define tournament-time in UK time so users can see in their local time. if you have users from different time zones, you can always let them select their timezone and manipulate UK time by adding-substracting hours.
btw if this is the answer you were looking for you can accept it as one ;)